How to get the latest id from an upsert Java MariaDB
My table is like that:
users (id, name, email, age)
id is autoincrement
name varchar and unique
email varchar
age decimal

I have a SQL Like this:
INSERT INTO users (name, email, age)
VALUES ('Alice', 'alice@example.com', 30)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    name = VALUES(name),
    age = VALUES(age);

With java I can retrieve the last generated id:
ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
                int generatedKey = 0;
                if (rs.next()) {
                    generatedKey = rs.getInt(1);

I can retrieve the generatedKey if there was an insert ok good.
But if my sql was about an update, there was no generated key becuase it was already there.
Is there a way to get the id from that specific insert/update?

No, because there might have been multiple records updated.  How can there be a duplicate key with that setup?  If "name" is the key (which you didn't say) then why do you have an "id" column at all?

@TimRoberts thanks, yes it makes sense I wasnt thinking on this perspective of concurrency. I'll have to do a select in order to get that id so

I'd like to explore the deeper issue here.  Can you show us the actual CREATE TABLE statement?  If "name" is not the primary key, then there can never be a duplicate key issue.  It will just add another "Alice" record.  If "name" is the primary key, then what's the point of an "id" field?

@TimRoberts email is unique, I'll update question

Then why don't you use that as the key?  Why have the autoincrement column at all?  It's pointless.

@Tim Roberts; Isn't that what they learn is school today? Table/entity uniqueness should be opaque and not related to any "business" constraint.

Well, there's a point to be made there, People DO change their email addresses fairly regularly, and if email is your key, then you have to change all the referencing tables.  It depends on how you're configured.  What do I know, I got my degree in 1980.

I hope the following approach can help you.
Step 1. Execute the insert preparedStatement.
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(
                "INSERT INTO users (name, email, age) VALUES (?, ?, ?) " +
                "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE " +
                "name = VALUES(name), email = VALUES(email), " +
                "id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id)");
// set the preparedStatement parameters
int returned = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

Step 2. Execute the select last insert id statement.
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS n");
resultSet.next();
int id = resultSet.getInt(1);

P.S. To understand whether a new row has been inserted or an existing one has been updated:
if (returned == 1) {
   System.out.println("Inserted");
} else {
   System.out.println("Updated");
}


This won't work. If you insert 2 records (id=1,name="foo"),(id=2, name="bar") last_insert_id() will return 2. If you now try to insert another record with name="foo" the statement should fail with a duplicate key error. The id can't be changed from 1 to 2, since id=2 already exists.

@GeorgRichter this work. If you try to insert row with name="foo", row will be updated but id stay the same (id=1). I use LAST_INSERT_ID with the argument in the INSERT statement (no arguments work differently).

Ahh I see - it's last_insert_id(id) not last_insert_id()

Just append a RETURNING to your insert statement
INSERT INTO users (name, email, age)
VALUES ('Alice', 'alice@example.com', 30)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    name = VALUES(name),
    age = VALUES(age)
RETURNING id;

and fetch the id afterwards.

(I think this is MariaDB-specific.)

Yes, and the question is tagged with mariadb and without mysql.
